# Does xpages support LESS/SASS (dynamic stylesheet languages)?

Tags: xpages

does xpages support LESS/SASS (http://lesscss.org/)? If yes How can i use it inside xpages?

Comment: At a minimum, the client-side approach to LESS would be identical to how you would use it on any other web server. Given the similarities between SSJS in XPages and the Rhino / Node equivalents, it's possible you could port the server-side parser, but that's likely to be more trouble than it's worth. Would make for a useful extension library, though. ;)

Comment: Thanks Tim, For now i will live with traditional CSS. IF time permits i will try to make a component to use it in xpages

Comment: If you do, explore the notion of "resource providers"; there's a reference implementation in the XSP Starter Kit -- http://openntf.org/p/XSP%20Starter%20Kit -- this would give you a way to add to the list of resource types you can choose from on an XPage / Custom Control. So in addition to script library, style sheet, meta data, etc., you could have an additional option for "LESS Style Sheet", for example.